# ¿Cómo obtener regresores en loop de regresiones en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Corro las regresiones utilizando ir_total como variable dependiente y combinaciones de a 3 de municipios como variables regresoras.

```
combinaciones <- apply(combn(independientes, m=3), 2, 
                      FUN=function(x){paste0("`", x, "`", collapse = ' + ')})
combinaciones

combinaciones <- sapply(paste("ir_total ~", combinaciones), as.formula)
modelos<-lapply(combinaciones, lm, df)

lapply(modelos, FUN=function(x) {cbind(r2=summary(x)$r.squared,
                                      coef1=coef(x)[2],
                                      coef2=coef(x)[3],
                                      coef3=coef(x)[4])})->datos


datos <- do.call(rbind, datos)
rownames(datos) <- NULL

datos
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero espero obtener una columna con las combinaciones de cada regresión y poder identificarlas dado que necesito manipular `datos` aplicando la función sort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible extraer los términos independientes de un modelo de regresión obtenido con `lm` de la siguiente manera:

`atributes(modelo$terms)$term.labels`

En este caso, también podemos obtenerlos a usando la función `coef()` de la siguiente manera, omitiendo el primer coeficiente que corresponde al intercepto:

`names(coef(x))[-1]`

De este modo, podemos hacer la siguiente modificación para obtener el nombre todos las variables independientes en una misma columna.

```
lapply(modelos, FUN = function(x) {
  cbind(
    r2 = summary(x)$r.squared, 
    coef1 = coef(x)[2], 
    coef2 = coef(x)[3],
    coef3 = coef(x)[4], 
    terminos = paste(attributes(x$terms)$term.labels, collapse = " ")
  )
})
```

Como en este caso sabemos que siempre tendremos tres variables independientes, podemos obtener el nombre de cada término en su propia columna.

```r
lapply(modelos, FUN = function(x) {
  cbind(
    r2 = summary(x)$r.squared, 
    coef1 = coef(x)[2], 
    coef2 = coef(x)[3],
    coef3 = coef(x)[4], 
    term1 = attributes(x$terms)$term.labels[1],
    term2 = attributes(x$terms)$term.labels[2],
    term3 = attributes(x$terms)$term.labels[3]
  )
})
```